# Gap between top of window and 'start bar'?

Tags: xfce

There's a small gap between the top of whichever window I'm using and the 'start bar' (sorry for using windows terminology, I'm not sure what it's called in this case :-s). It's about the same height at the title bar of my window. For some reason VLC can be moved into this space, so I'm not sure what's stopping anything else going there.

Ubuntu studio with XFCE4, if that helps.

Cheers!

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you see.  Could you post a screen shot somewhere and provide the link to the jpeg/png file back here in a comment and I'll add it to your question...

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, I'd added an extra panel by mistake, it was a little taller than the main panel, so caused the gap. Deleted that panel and everything's back to normal

Comment: I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)